# Firebase & JavaScript - How to update object with specific ID value?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[Image of Database Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AV4x6.png)

I have a firebase database with "4 Tables".

Each "table" haves data from each object that exists in **TLogin**. These objects are all identified with an **ID value**.

What I want to do is to update a specific object value by it´s **ID** value.

For example, I want to set in the "table" **TProgresso** the **XP** value to **"10"** where the **ID** haves the value **"2"**.

How can I make this update?

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first have to query for the `TProgresso` sub-nodes that verifies `id === 2` and then update the value of `xp`(s), as follows:

```
  var db = firebase.database();

  db.ref('TProgresso')
    .orderByChild('id')
    .equalTo(2)
    .once('value')
    .then(function(snapshot) {
      snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
        childSnapshot.ref.child('xp').set(10);
      });
    });
```

You'll find more detail in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data) about the `orderByChild()` and `equalTo()` methods.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It solved my question! You really deserve those reputation points  Thank´s a lot!

Comment: @cutiko because the nodes with values `-LSJG...` or `-LSJH...` are keys automatically generated by Firebase and the OP does not know them upfront.